# Is posting with a link_to a good Rails Practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've already asked something about link_to here : [Multiple posts handled by links and named routes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214368/multiple-posts-handled-by-links-and-named-routes-in-rails)

I've not gotten a reply yet and in the process, i was thinking. Is posting with a link a good practice ? Back in my php days i would actually do that a lot, but do you think one should be doing that in Rails ?

It sure is pretty convenient i suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with performing POST requests with `link_to`. I'd even say it is encouraged!

See section "3 Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)" on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html